# How would Spanish text at bottom of English content page change how our pages rank?

Tags: seo, google-search, pagerank, language

On our real estate site we are planning to put Spanish text (2-3 lines) at bottom of every page. Except for the bottom part, all the content is in English.

I am new to Page Rank & Google search optimization. So i have few queries related to that:

- How this Spanish content will affect rankings?
- Will it help to search through Spanish words? I mean, if user searches using Spanish words will our pages come in search results?

Comment: This same exact questions wads closed previously as a duplicate. Asking it again does not make it acceptable.

Comment: @JohnConde - You asked to be specific....Following that I edited the question...Now it is specific about Spanish content at bottom of English page only....So how it is duplicate ? Also my edited question was not reopened...That's why I asked as new question...If you have knowledge you can share as an answer rather that marking as duplicate....Thanks....

Comment: The only difference between this question and the first time you asked is in this question you added the title to the bottom of the question. That is not more specific.

Comment: I don't agree with you @JohnConde, this question is way more specific than the *already answered* one. There are a bunch of questions asked everyday in SE that are way more doubtful than this one and are still answered.

Comment: You probably mean "Google rankings" not Pagerank.  Pagerank is a metric about links to a page which is not influenced by content (Spanish or otherwise).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - As per your link, it is duplicate. And yeah I am concerned about effect of having two languages in one page in search results. I followed the other question you pointed. But still I find ambiguity in the answer.

Comment: When it comes to SEO, clear answers are in short supply.   Weigh the evidence and decide what is right for your site and your users.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - One more question. With Spanish content on English page, will Google identify that content is unique & different from other websites's pages ? Because if with Spanish content Google's algorithm consider the page's content as unique/different then it is useful for gaining authorization.